# Common solution for $f(x) = f'(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

I encountered the following problem in Real Analysis:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and assume there is no $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=f'(x)=0$. Show that $S=\{x\mid 0\le x\le 1, f(x)=0\}$ is finite.

I have solved this problem by observing that $S$ is compact and in case it is infinite, the limit point $\alpha$ of $S$ gives  a contradiction by negating the hypothesis since $f(\alpha)=f'(\alpha)=0$.

I want to apply the contra positive statement of the problem to the function $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$. Since for the chosen $f(x)$, $S$ is infinite ($\frac {1} {n\pi}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ belongs to $S$), I should be able to conclude that there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=f'(x)=0$. But Wolfram says there is no such $x$. Am I wrong or is Wolfram wrong? Please help.

Comment: Were you able to define $f$ at $x=0$ on WolframAlpha?

Comment: oops! I forgot that. Of course f(0)=0

Comment: Don't doubt the results which you have proved.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Sometimes confidence levels go down.

Comment: Just to boost your confidence, asking questions like these and not taking anything on faith enhances your understanding as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you define $f(0)$? If you do not define it, the domain of $f$ is not compact. If you define $f(0)=0$, then $f'(0)=f(0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.